# python plot 3d color map

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 3 1-D arrays, for the X values, Y values and Z values.
I want to make a 2-d plot with X vs Y and have Z in color.

However every time I try I run I get

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

currently I have:

```
X=np.array(X)
Y=np.array(Y)
Z=np.array(Z)

fig = pyplot.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
p = ax.scatter(X,Y,Z)
```

I have also tried

```
fig, ax = pyplot.figure()
p = ax.pcolor(X,Y,Z,cmap = cm.RdBu)
cb = fig.colorbar(p,ax=ax)
```

both give me the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of [`plt.scatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) expects input like:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(x, y, s=20, ...)
```

Which is not `(x,y,z)`. You were setting `s`, the size of the points, as your Z value. To give a "Z" value of color, pass it as the `c` parameter:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

# Example points that use a color proportional to the radial distance
N = 2000
X = np.random.normal(size=N)
Y = np.random.normal(size=N)
Z = (X**2+Y**2)**(1/2.0)

plt.scatter(X,Y,c=Z,linewidths=.1)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @bobruels44 What new error? I don't see another comment or edit. Either way, a completely new question should be posed as that - a new question.

Comment: Sorry still sorting through them, I noticed a more detailed edit, and I'm just quickly trying stupid things.

Comment: I'm still getting the attribute error, even though I'm using numpy arrays.

Comment: It's impossible to diagnose the problem without a more complete example. If you edit your question to a minimal example that produces the error we can take a look at it.

Comment: This basically is the entire plotting routine. The rest of the code is building those arrays.